# select from database table rows that are not in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table of 'entries' in a MYSQL database. I have another table that records activity on those entries, with the id of the entry as a foreign key. I want to select from my first table entries that do not appear in the second table.

How can I use SQL to make this happen? Do I have to iterate through both tables and compare every entry with every other entry? Is there an easier way to do this?

ex. I have a table with an entry data column and a user name column. I have another table with an entry id column and a user id column. I want to select from my first table all of the entries which do not appear in the second table with a given user id.

Thanks ahead of time. I have been struggling with this experiment for a while. I imagine I have to join the two tables somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several ways to achieve this, `NOT IN`, `NOT EXISTS`, `LEFT JOIN / NULL` check.  Here's one with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM FirstTable T
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM SecondTable T2 
    WHERE T.Id = T2.Id
    )
```

Comment: Gervs can you clarify?

Comment: @user3667450 -- there's an age old debate that when using `EXISTS`, you can use `SELECT *` or `SELECT 1`.  Most modern DBMS's will actually produce the same execution plan for these queries.  I prefer the readability of `SELECT *`, but they both work just as well.  So if you would prefer, you can write `...WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1...`.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you want to select all rows where the foreign key doesn't match anything in the other table. This should do the trick:

```
SELECT *
FROM Data A
RIGHT JOIN Entry B
ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE A.ID IS NULL
```

[Here's a handy chart that illustrates how to use joins for stuff like this.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins/Visual_SQL_JOINS_orig.jpg)

You can also use NOT IN, and the mechanics for this one are actually a bit easier to understand.

```
SELECT *
FROM Data A
WHERE A.ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM Entry)
```